# How can I get google+ user posts in an iOS APP

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'm using google ios sdk to integrate my app with google+ sign in.(I've searched google+ sdk, and found that google has deprecated this sdk, and suggest we use google sdk instead).

But after I login, get user id and access token, and try to get user post with the following command:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: OAuth {access_token}" -X GET https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/{user_Id}/activities/user
```

I always get such error:

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

I've requested following permissions:

```
scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read",
```

And I found the doc on google:

```
Warning: The Google+ Sign-In button and the plus.login scope used by Google+ Sign-In are not currently supported for use with the Google+ Domains API. Requests that are made to the Google+ Domains API using an authentication token granted for the plus.login scope, or generated by the Google+ Sign-In button, will fail.
```

So, how can we get google+ user posts user google login?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, What I want is google+ API, not google+ domain API.
So using google+ API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{user_Id}/activities/public
```

Can get user posts.